# DNN - dnn.js reference duplicated when ClientResourceManagement is enabled

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I get duplicate script references, causing js errors in my DNN install. I have ClientResourceManagement (CRM) enabled (and there's seemingly no way to disable it)

The problematic script references are below:

```
<script src="/js/dnn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script src="/js/dnn.js?cdv=98" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**How do I get rid of the duplicates or disable the CRM?**

p.s. turns out, the duplicate reference was not the problem; once I've set the debug to "false" in web.config, all js errors went away. Have no idea what caused them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your skin or custom module isn't adding the first DNN.js reference?

As for disabling CRM, that is done via the HOST/Host Settings page.